# validation issue

Tags: .net, asp.net

how to make button cause validation for some controls and other not..

i have button ..

and i have link button in gridview .

i have textbox ..(has required field validator)

and i have textbox in the gridview.(has required field validator)

what i wanna is : when click the link button is to validate only the textbox in the gridview.

and when click the button is to validate only the external textbox

how to do some thing like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation groups should be able to do what you want. The idea is that they can be assigned to specific textboxes and validators to trigger validation only for specific groups of elements on a page.

You can find out more information here http://www.dotnet-guide.com/validationgroups.html